# error handling in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my project to catch all the PHP errors I have set up my error handling mechanism as follows:

1. I have set `error_reporting()` in `index.php` file which overrides
   anything in the `php.ini` file
2. An error handler is set in `system/codeigniter/CodeIgniter.php` using
   `set_error_handler` - this error handler, `_exception_handler`,  is
   found in `system/codeigniter/Common.php`
3. The `_exception_handler` function ignores `E_STRICT` errors, calls the
   `show_php_error` function From the Exceptions system library if the
   severity is that specified by your `error_reporting()` function in
   `index.php` and logs the error according to whatever you have set up in your `config.php` file
4. The handler returns `FALSE` so after this PHP goes on to handle the
   error however it normally would according your `error_reporting` level
   and `display_errors` setting.

The thing that is puzzling me is that `E_ERROR` errors i.e. fatal errors don’t seem to be being caught by `_exception_handler` at all. It’s not just that `show_php_error` isn’t being called, it looks like the function just isn’t being called for them. This is obviously a problem as it means that they aren’t get handled by `show_php_error` or logged. For example if I deliberately mistype `$this->load->views('foo');` in a controller, the handler doesn’t get called.

Any suggestion about error handling would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think it may be an issue with PHP itself without being able to test it. If you see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php#70126 you'll see that in this case, an E_ERROR causes a similar effect to what E_PARSE would do.

Comment: what environment are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now this is a rather big debate:
Whether you should catch the fatal errors or not.
Some say that they are FATAL so you dont know in which condition is the system but I will go with the "try to do the cleanup if the error occured".
In order to catch ALL fatal errors you will need to setup a pre_system hook.
go to application/config/hooks.php and enter

```
$hook['pre_system'][] = array(
'class' => 'PHPFatalError',
'function' => 'setHandler',
'filename' => 'PHPFatalError.php',
'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

after that go to hooks directory and add your handling of the error:

```
<?php
    class PHPFatalError {

    public function setHandler() {
            register_shutdown_function('handleShutdown');
        }

    }

    function handleShutdown() {
        if (($error = error_get_last())) {
            ob_start();
                echo "<pre>";
            var_dump($error);
                echo "</pre>";
            $message = ob_get_clean();
            sendEmail($message);
            ob_start();
            echo '{"status":"error","message":"Internal application error!"}';
            ob_flush();
            exit();
        }
    }
```

as you can see we are using the register_shutdown_function to run a function that checks if an error had occured and if it had send it via email to the developer.
This setup is working flawlessly for over 2 years in several CI projects that I have been working with.

Comment: Hi tix, i feel this is really good approach but in my case i had developed a customized approach where i had the register_shutdown_function() in a helper class to handle overall errors of the project... Thank YOu

Comment: Well you can stack up the register_shutdown_function() but there is not other way (as far as I know) that you can catch fatal errors other than using a presystem hook.

Comment: As stated in https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/4160, changing default `shutdown` handler is not safe.
Anyways, `_shutdown_handler` calls `_error_handler` which can be override within a custom `Exception` class as @Gergelin said.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this answer under an other question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3675357), and i think it is also useful for anyone reading this question. 
"For codeigniter specific error handling, you can override its 'Exception' library class by creating **My_Exception** class in your application/libraries folder. Copy original library function signatures into it and put in your code. It will surely work."

Answer (score 0):

> Simply you can handle all type of error in one file which is display
> your client because of php error or any other error is not good to
> display client.

*Simply place file Common_Exceptions.php in core folder . Common is my because in config file I have declare $config['subclass_prefix'] = 'Common_';*

Copy system\core\Exceptions.php file and paste in core\Common_Excepions file **(class Common_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions)** and do your change in this file and call view  for your want and display to client when error come.

**NOTE: $config['log_threshold'] = 1; enable in config file for errorlog write and after you see what error come.**

*One more suggestion on view file which is display when error is come there place time so when you see in log then match this time and find which error is come that time*